# Can someone how to understand this clamAV debug report?

Tags: clamav

```
LibClamAV debug: ELF: ELF class 2 (64-bit)
LibClamAV debug: ELF: Number of program headers: 6
LibClamAV debug: ELF: Number of sections: 38
LibClamAV debug: Matched signature for file type ZIP-SFX at 859005
LibClamAV debug: matcher_run: performing regex matching on full map: 10777882+55894(10833776) >= 10833776
LibClamAV debug: matcher_run: performing regex matching on full map: 10777882+55894(10833776) >= 10833776
LibClamAV debug: FP SIGNATURE: 973043cb83781eefbad3a86221ee9f9a:10833776:Unix.Malware.Kinsing-7812070-0
```

what is the meaning of below line

```
LibClamAV debug: FP SIGNATURE: 973043cb83781eefbad3a86221ee9f9a:10833776:Unix.Malware.Kinsing-7812070-0
```

Comment: Google `Unix.Malware.Kinsing`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have identified the Kinsing Malware which targets Docker.

Comment: yes but it is not related to docker and any idea how to understand below line. don't know what is FP SIGNATURE and that checksum and  10833776
FP SIGNATURE: 973043cb83781eefbad3a86221ee9f9a:10833776:Unix.Malware.Kinsing-7812070-0